# reverse string recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, reverse

Hello
Why my reverse method that uses recursion isn't working?
The print statement shows that the operation is done correctly but at the end it seems like only the very ast char of the entire String is assigned to h.

```
    public static String reverse(String s,String h){

    if(s.length()==0){

        return s;

    } else {


        h+=s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        System.out.println(h);//FOR TEST
        s=s.substring(0,s.length()-1);
        reverse(s,h);
        return h;
    }

}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
 return reverse(s,h);
```

instead of
  return h;

i.e:

```
public static String reverse(String s,String h){

    if(s.length() == 0){

        return h;

    } else {


        h+=s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        System.out.println(h);//FOR TEST
        s=s.substring(0,s.length()-1);
        return reverse(s,h); //NOTICE THE CHANGE HERE,
    }

}
```

Comment: Not quite: this returns an empty string.

Comment: @ trutheality s will be empty but h will be s converted so thats what will be returned as s will be empty thank you Cybernate, but i still dont get why returning h wont work as in my code

Comment: @JBoy: In your code you are not using/re-assigning the value returned by the recursive call made to reverse(s,h) right before calling return h and hence your code will always return the value assigned to h in first iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Strings in Java are immutable.  So in this code:

```
private static void foo(String x) {
    x += "bar";
}

public static void main() {
    String a = "foo";
    foo(a);
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Only `"foo"` will be printed.  It works the same way as if the type were `int`.

So your `reverse` function needs to do something with the return value.  When you call `reverse(s,h)` you are throwing away the return value from the recursive call.  You need to incorporate it:

```
String rec = reverse(s,h);
return ... something involving rec ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

```
public static String reverse(String s,String h){

    if(s.length()==0){

        return h; /// This needs to return the reversed string (h).

    } else {


        h+=s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        System.out.println(h);//FOR TEST
        s=s.substring(0,s.length()-1);
        h = reverse(s,h);   /// You need to use the return value
        return h;
    }

}
```

It looks like you were trying to change h using a return-by-reference-parameter. You have to remember that in Java everything (including references to objects) is passed by value. Once you write `s=s.substring(0,s.length()-1);`, `s` becomes a reference to a different `String` object, and that change is not propagated to the calling function.

Also, there is a way to implement this with only one input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is better for reversing a string using a recursive method :

```
public class Reversestringbyrecursivefunction {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("[?] Enter String('q' for exit)> ");
            String str=input.next();
            if(str.equals("q"))
                break;
            System.out.println("this string created by reversed recursive function : "+revers(str));
            System.out.print("\n==========================\n");
        }
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t[ GOOD LUCK!!! ]\n");
    }
    static String revers(String str)
    {
        if(str.length()<=1)
            return str;
        else
            return revers(str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()))+revers(str.substring(0, str.length()-1));
    }
}
```

but , for best performance you should change this line :

```
return revers(str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()))+revers(str.substring(0, str.length()-1));
```

to :

```
return str.substring(str.length()-1)+revers(str.substring(1, str.length()-1)+str.substring(0,1);
```

in prior line: in best performance and in one stage you can swap only 1 character of input string . but , in new line: in one stage you can swap 2 character of input string