# Recursive Reverse Word method not able to get past first letter

Tags: java, string, recursion, reverse, sentence

When I run the tester class it can't get past the first letter. It outputs an "!" mark instead of continuing to print the rest of the word reversed. Can't figure why it keeps getting hungup. The recursive method seems to be stuck and unable to continue past the first character. Instead of printing  "!olleH" I only get "!". Thanks!

```
/**
   Class reverses text of word
*/

public class Sentence
{
    private String text="";



    /**
        Constructs a sentence
        @param word
    */
    public Sentence(String textIN)
    {
        text=textIN;
    }

    /**
        gets text
        @return text
    */
    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }

    /**
        Reverse word

    */
    public String reverse()
    {
        if (text.length() <= 1)
        {
            return text;
        }

        else
        {
            char val = text.charAt(0);
            text=text.substring(1);
            return reverse() + val;
        }
    }
}


/**
   A tester class for reversing a sentence.
*/
public class SentenceTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Sentence greeting = new Sentence("Hello!");
      greeting.reverse();
      System.out.println(greeting.getText());
      System.out.println("Expected: !olleH");
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse string recursive method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248101/reverse-string-recursive-method)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final program (just changed the return statement):

/**
Class reverses text of word
*/

public class Sentence
{
    private String text="";

`/**
 Constructs a sentence
 @param word
*/
    public Sentence(String textIN)
    {
        text=textIN;
    }

    /**
     gets text
     @return text
    */
    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
    /**
    Reverse word
    */
    public String reverse()
    {
        if (text.length() <= 1)
        {
            return text;
        }
        else
        {
            char val = text.charAt(0);
            text=text.substring(1);
            return (text=reverse() + val);
        }
    }
}`

the reason is simple - String is immutable. Every time you want it to change assign it back again.

Answer (score 0):

From a read-through of your code, your reverse method seems to work - it returns a reverse of the original text. However, it does this by altering the value of `text`, and it never puts the final value into `text`.

What actually happens is that `text` gets shorter by one character (removed from the front) until there is only one character left - the `!`.

So, you could solve the problem in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Sentence greeting = new Sentence("Hello!");
    String result = greeting.reverse();
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println("Expected: !olleH");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you like it that way. Just for information, you could use below -

```
String reversedString = new StringBuilder("Original String").reverse().toString();
```

One more thing, your code will not work if you pass null :)

The problem with your code is, you are modifying text in else block.

```
text = text.substring(1);
```

So at the end it holds only **!**

Comment: While that does provide the overall functionality required, it doesn't solve the particular problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: But that last character is appended with all the other characters on the way back out the call stack. The real problem is that `text` is modified each time, and then the OP is only printing `text`, not the result of the `reverse()` method.